# Master thesis on developping Twincat3 driver

Tags: plc, iec61131-3

If there is any PLC programmer or Twincat3 user out there. I would like to write my master thesis on Twincat3 in a company. Basically, They have different kinds of the Test bench, and they want someone to develop drivers for them. I have no experience with PLC or C++ or IEC61131 languages. Is it possible to learn any of these in 3 months, and then start writing the thesis? I have three months of Internship time before starting. I am having a bit of doubt. Even though it is daunting as an Electrical engineering student, I have no other options.
I thank you in Advance.
Also, The test benches are mainly Powerelectronics or Electrical machine test bench. I believe I need to automate the test processes in twincat3.
Best Regards

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about academic life, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Good choice with TwinCAT 3. TwinCAT 3 is very capable, and quite easy to learn (of course dependent on your background, but generally a good platform to work on).

All I can support you with is a link to a TwinCAT 3 tutorial that I've created that is free of charge (available on YouTube):
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLimaF0nZKYHz3I3kFP4myaAYjmYk1SowO

There are also some other resources available both on YouTube and on the website. I've created a set of [links here](https://alltwincat.com/links/) to help you find all the resources you might need.

To answer your question I would say it depends. Three months is not much time, especially considering you probably have a lot of other things that need to go in there (doing studies, writing the thesis, implementation, conclusions etc). It depends on the complexity of your project (it's not very specific what "writing drivers for them" means). If it's a simple project (including a very basic set of I/Os) it might be do-able. If it's anything more complex (like needing to add a front-end, doing motion control and maybe even safety) then it's most likely going to be hard to finish it in three months.

But again, I think more details on what you want to achieve is necessary.

Comment: Possibly because you are answering an off topic question. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
  Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: Hello Jakob,
Thank you, I have been following your Youtube channel. The master thesis will be 6 months, before that they want to give three months of internship to learn about the test benches and twincat3, as they don't have anyone expert in twincat3 in the company. Obviusly, I have to prove myself during this time. My only concern is that, regarding my poor programming. I am confident about electrical systems but, very bad on implementing embeded softwares.